# Deleting array elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, element

All, I want to delete specific array elements of one array from the other. Here is an example. The arrays are a long list of words though.

```
A = ['at','in','the']
B = ['verification','at','done','on','theresa']
```

I would like to delete words that appear in A from B.

```
B = ['verification','done','theresa']
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
for word in A:
    for word in B:
        B = B.replace(word,"")
```

I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

What should I use to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension to get the full answer:

```
[x for x in B if x not in A]
```

However, you may want to know more about replace, so ...

python list has no replace method.  If you just want to remove an element from a list, set the relevant slice to be an empty list.  For example:

```
>>> print B
['verification', 'at', 'done', 'on', 'theresa']
>>> x=B.index('at')
>>> B[x:x+1] = []
>>> print B
['verification', 'done', 'on', 'theresa']
```

Note that trying to do the same thing with the value `B[x]` will not delete the element from the list.

Comment: Also, `B.pop(x)`, or even better `B.remove('at')` would work here.

Comment: `B[x:x+1] = []` -> `del B[x:x+1]`

Comment: @Patrick one fringe benefit of presenting this array technique is that the same form can be used to insert multiple elements.  For example, `x=[1,2,3];x[1:2]=[5,6,7];x` returns `[1,5,6,7,3]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok to delete duplicates in B and don't care about order, you can stick up with sets:

```
>>> A = ['at','in','the']
>>> B = ['verification','at','done','on','theresa']
>>> list(set(B).difference(A))
['on', 'done', 'theresa', 'verification']
```

In this case you'll get a significant speedup as lookup in set is *much* faster than in list. Actually, in this case it's better A and B to be sets

Comment: "lookup in set is much faster than in dictionary" -- I'm not sure quite what you mean here, as I don't see dictionaries in any of the other answers, but lookup in a set is basically the same as key lookup in a dictionary.

Comment: I think he meant "lookup in set is much faster than in list".  The question is about lists, everyone is talking about lists, and this way it is a correct statement.

Comment: you're right, it's all about lists. Lookup in lis is O(n), lookup in set/dictionary is O(1)

Comment: However the result's order will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try removing the elements from B, ex :

```
A = ['at','in','the']
B = ['verification','at','done','on','theresa']
print B
for w in A:
    #since it can throw an exception if the word isn't in B
    try: B.remove(w)
    except: pass
print B
```