# NameError on list that's initialized in the constructor [Python3]

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm extremely new to programming, and my projects thus far have consisted of Frankenstein-esque monsters of stitched together sample codes.  This is my first project that I am developing largely independently.  So far it has not gone well.  It's fun though!

I'm working on a class function that returns only the values of one list that aren't in another given list.  I found code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459246/deleting-array-elements-in-python), but I'm getting a NameError.

My code:

```
def __init__ (self, extracted): #Constructor
    allWords = extracted
    shelfFile = shelve.open('knownWordsPersistant') #Opens preexisting shelve module file
    knownWords = shelfFile['knownWords'] #The list that the error specifies

def getUnknownWords (self):
    return [x for x in allWords if x not in knownWords] #Line that causes error
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack 
Hanson\Desktop\Programming\Python\VocabFinder\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    possUnknWrds = knownWordsObject.getUnknownWords(vocabArray)
  File "C:\Users\Jack 
Hanson\Desktop\Programming\Python\VocabFinder\KnownWordsUpdater.py", line 
16, in getUnknownWords
    if (inArray[i] not in knownWords):
NameError: name 'knownWords' is not defined
```

If you need any more context or information, I'll happily provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: define object variable without initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506091/python-define-object-variable-without-initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue....

You should set an attribute on the class `self.knownWords` and then use `self.knownWords` in your function. Same thing for `allWords`.

In your code you're attempting to reference local variables in `getUnknownWords` which aren't defined as the error message indicates.

Also, you shouldn't camel case things. Use underscores.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I know I should really be using the official style guide, but at least for my private work, I prefer the look of camel case.